# Signal Method not Found even Though Method is Referenced in Godot C#

Tags: c#, signals-slots, godot4

I have been following [this](https://youtu.be/fibjT1UUSNE?si=76evuXazEo1-D9Ww&t=304) tutorial on creating a Character Movement System where I ran into a problem related to signals. I was trying to have Spikes `Node2D` with an `Area2D` child send a signal when a body entered its CollisionShape2D. I was successfully able to connect the signal to the Spikes `Node2D` and I `Ctrl + C` the receiver method then added it to Spike Script.

```
private void _on_area_2d_body_entered()
{
    GD.Print("Body has entered");
}
```

On VS, it says that there is 1 reference to the receiver method, though I cant seem to access the code where it is called. That being said, whenever my Player `CharacterBody2D` passes through the Spikes' `Sprite2D`, which is perfectly aligned with the CollisionShape2D, I get the following debug error:

```
emit_signalp: Error calling from signal 'body_entered' to callable:
'Node2D(SpikeTrap.cs)::_on_area_2d_body_entered': Method not found.
```

I followed the tutorial, and the guy added `object body` as parameters in the method. When I did the same, I got no references to my method. I have no clue what is going wrong here.

I watched that part in the video multiple times, and I searched through google and the Godot documentation to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the tutorial, the guy passes in a parameter `object body`, which does not work anymore. You have to pass in specific nodes, like `Node2D` or `CharacterBody2D`. Like so:

```
private void _on_area_2d_body_entered(CharacterBody2D body)
    {
        GD.Print("Body: " + body + " has entered");
    }
```